# How to get status of the release (success, failure) with powershell using Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using `post` method to create release in `Azure DevOps`:

`$url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/"+$organization+"/"+$project+"/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1"
$body = @{definitionId = 9} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}`

My pipeline is simple with single stage which executes automatically. Release creation and execution works fine.

But how to get status of my stage/s using `powershell` and `REST API`. I need to keep executing script while Release is in progress and initiate script failure if any of the stages fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DefinitionID and EnvironmentIDs (you will get this from your initial POST response), you can query the last release and check for  "deploymentStatus" value in intervals and exit when the status changes to "succeeded/failed/cancelled".

(collectionURL)/(teamproject)/_apis/Release/deployments?definitionId="+RELEASE_DEFINITIONID+"&definitionEnvironmentId="+RELEASE_DEFINITIONENVIRONMENTID?api-version=1.0

[image]

Comment: marked as the answer,but they not except votes:
`Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`